# microsoft PPL library: concurrent_vector push_back data only once

Tags: concurrency, concurrent-vector

I have a Concurrency::concurrent_vector and want to push_back thread safe a new element only in case it not already exists (that's why I have to perform a search first). How can I accomplish this ? 
I need a concurrent collection that it's thread safe at iterator access(write,read same element) and also permits what I wrote above.

Question refinement:
What would be the best container to use if it's mostly searched concurrently, if element is not found (more rare) an insert/push_back would be needed and in case search element is found (most of the cases) update to an element is *needed* (concurrent update of the same iterator)

From what is already available in VS2010 I saw concurrent_vector but that it is not safe at updating the same element and also it seems that I need an extra lock in case an element is not found and I need to add an element because of that. What do you think ? Is there something I can use to eliminate external locks (whole container locks)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the case described probably the best would be to use (from Visual Studio) the concurrent_unordered_map container which is a hash based container that ensures concurrent iteration, iterator access (as long as the updates/reads to the same element value is synchronized!), push_back-s, element access based on key (operator []).

The container implementation is available as part of the [Concurrency Runtime Sample Pack](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/concrtextras/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=5189)
In case look-up by key is not necessary one could also use other concurrent containers:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504906.aspx